# Is step counter supported on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I am now working with step counter sensor on Android and I have tried "react-native-sensor-manager".

However nothing is shown when running the code and when I look into the API of SensorEvent, I don't see the word Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER so I wonder whether step counter is supported or not.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that there is a step counter sensor. But you can calculate steps manually based on accylometer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am not sure how to get steps from accelerometer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/kprimice/react-native-sensor-manager#step-counter). I didn't try yet. If you already found something I will thanks you if you can share it.